# How many background process PHP can handle simultaneously?

Tags: php, background-process

I have a server with the following specifications:

- 1 vCPU
- 1 GB RAM
- 25 GB SSD

Configured with Linux `Ubuntu 18.04`, `apache 2` and `php 7.2`.

Let's assume that for each visitor entering my page, I run a command in background mode, where it counts from 0 to 100,000 - 1 million:

**index.php**

```
exec("php ./countToOneMilion.php > /dev/null &");//This code runs a php file in background mode (if the user closes a browser window, a count still continues)
```

**countToOneMilion.php**

```
$number = mt_rand(100000, 1000000);//Generate a random number
for ($i = 0; $i <= $number; $i++) {
    echo $i;
}
```

According to `phpinfo()`, the `memory_limity` parameter of my server, is set to `127M` (which is the default value when installing php and apache).

Now, let's assume that 20 visitors entered in my page. In that case, how will PHP execute the processes in background mode (since counting from 0 to 1 million is often a time-consuming task)?

Will it run 20 times simultaneously (dividing the 127M by 20, thats the number of processes) or will some processes stay on a waiting list until the other processes are over? Or is PHP only able to execute one process at a time (causing the last task from the last user to wait a considerable amount of time to get the count from 0 to 1 million?)

Comment: I think `memory_limit` is a limit on each PHP process, not all the processes combined.

Comment: You would get better answers if you described what you are trying to achieve. In general, what you are describing can't be calculated like that. The only way to really know is to actually run it and measure it.

Comment: Counting to one million is not really time consuming. You can see the result of an adaptation of your code [here](http://stackoverflow.dev.lbader.de/56227232/test.php).
Counting takes less than a second.